# Vector like drawing for zoomable UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, calayer

I have a zoomable UIScrollView with some `CATextLayer`s and simple `CALayer`s in it.
They get rendered fine but the problem is when they are zoomed they become blurry. (Even if I redraw them)

What would be my options to get my text not blurry when the view is zoomed? 
Should I use another thing? enable something in `CATextLayer`/`CALayer`? Any idea is welcomed ;)

I am using `CALayer`s because, as suggested in documentation, `CALayer`s are lighter than `UIViews` and I have hundreds of them. Currently it works smoothly. I have tried with `UIWebView` and my `CALayer` version is faster ;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

iOS rasterizes the text before the scale-up occurs, that's why it's so blurry. You only need to fix one property of your CATextLayer, contentsScale, to get a higher quality render after zooming. Implement this UIScrollViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                       withView:(UIView *)view
                        atScale:(float)scale
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] 
                     forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
    uglyBlurryTextLayer.contentsScale = scale;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

This tells the layer to use more pixels to render the text, and it disables Core Animation when making that particular change.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. This is what I was looking for. Just great! ;)

Comment: This doesn't quite work - it changes the size of the rendered text too. As you zoom in, the text gets smaller, as you zoom out, it gets larger (so that the same number of pixels is being used on screen, I think?).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.